# Get grandParent using xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="myclass">
  <span>...</span>
  <div>
       <table>
              <colgroup>...</>
              <tbody>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td> 
                              <input ...name="myname" ...> 
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>...</tr>
              <tbody>
       </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

this is my html code ... I have attribute "name" ..so I can access   tag ...but from this line I want to access top  element.
One way is that I write `driver.find_element_by_xpath('..')` 6-7 times to get that parent but I dont know how many steps I have to go above. I simply want a xpath expression or similar thing to access top .

I'm using Selenium webdriver with python

Answer (score 11):

Instead of targeting a deeper level element and going up in the tree, you can select the higher level element and test for a descendant node attribute:

```
.//div[@class="myclass"][.//input[@name="myname"]]
```

Comment: yeah ..I know that. but my problem is just opposite.

Comment: hmmm, maybe I didn't understand your problem, but going down the tree, finding a target element, and going back up may not be the most efficient. That's why I thought finding potential `<div class="myclass">` elements and then filtering those that have your target `<input ...name="myname" ...>` would fit

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to @Paul's answer, you can navigate up from the `input` to the `div` via the [ancestor axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), however, I can't see why his solution wouldn't work for you:

```
//input[@name='myname']/ancestor::div[@class = 'myclass']
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with StuartLC BUT would change it to;

```
 //input[@name='myname']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'myclass')]
```

I would always use a 'contains' on class attribute as the class can contain multiple values but unlike CSS selectors, Xpath treats it as a literal string.

ie. StuartLC's xpath would fail if another class was added to the div

Also, if you do want to find it from the 'myname' element you can use;

```
self::*/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'myclass')]
```

Comment: Indeed, `contains` will add robustness to change :)

Answer (score 2):

```
grandparent = element.find_element_by_xpath('../..')
```