# How to get a td element by a div which in that td?

Tags: java, selenium

There are a div in td, How can i get td element by div?

```
<td>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <div class='A'></div>
    </div>
<td>
```

I just could get parent element to A.But how can i get the td element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get grandParent using xpath in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578785/get-grandparent-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: While the proposed duplicate solves this for the Python language, the answers tell you how to construct the XPath expression, which will be same for Java as it is for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below:

```
String a=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='A']//parent::div//parent::td")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find element by `xpath`, utilize `ancestor`:

```
//div[@class='A']/ancestor::td
```